# exporting section in betheme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i want to export section in betheme for using in another site that also have betheme

I Found the export section function in the Live builder.

Click on export , it tells you the section is exported but where to?

No into clipboard anyway. How does this option work?
[export option image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CW2b8.png)
[exported showed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrERP.png)

Answer (score 0):

It exports it to memory, not the clipboard. I tried this yesterday but within the same site. It may also work between sites. Give it a try.

After exporting a section, I went to the target page and clicked import. You are given options about where you want it placed. It worked.